# How to open a .k format (I think it is made with IDRISI product) with open source software

Tags: qgis, import, saga, terrset

I just received a `.k` file which I know it was made with a IDRISI software (I do not know which). I searched the web and I did not find many information on this format apart for a very essential page with few useful info. It seems from what I read that this could be a kind of container for the IDRISI raster files? Am I wrong?

I tried (of course not successfully) to import it (with the raster import functions) in QGIS, GRASS GIS, SAGA GIS. GRASS and QGIS returned this message:

> D:\XXXXXX\RESULTAT_TAYMA_4500.K is not a supported raster data source
>   Ungridded dataset: At line 4, X is 4.000000, where as 1.000000 was expected

I work on Windows 7 with open source software (mainly QGIS, GRASS and SAGA).
Does anybody have some tips about this file format?

Comment: Can you (privately) make the file available for inspection?

Comment: Thaks makusN but I found a way... just opening the file in a test editor and importing the points as a point cloud into SAGA. Still I do not understand what a .k file is... thanks anyway

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.  You can submit your fix as an answer to your own question and mark it as correct, so if someone else has the same question they can find it easier.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to close the question as suggested by DPierce, since I found a solution:
just opened the .K file made in Idrisi with a editor (I used notepad++) and saved all the points coordinates in .csv format. I still do not have any specific info on the .K file format, nut it is irrilevant at this point.